# Emergency exit in Python without goto

Tags: python, goto

In C I regularly use goto to jump out of the middle of a function and unravel anything I did in the function when an exception occurs that can't be handled gracefully; for example close file descriptors, free allocated memory that won't be used, such as

```
error3:
    for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
        nameDelete(names[j]);
    }
error:2
    free(names);
error1:
    close(fd);
error0:
    exit(-1);
```

Early in the code before I open fd I'd jump out at error0:, later at error1: and so forth as I grab resources.

Python doesn't have this construct. Instead I'm looking at condition after condition where I have to put the appropriate code in over and over, and where if I change the function to grab a resource at some point I need to ensure all premature exits below it handle that resource properly instead of at one point.

I'm not tied to the goto syntax (and I've read Dijkstra), however I'm wondering if there's a common pattern for this kind of operation in Python. A (quick) survey of Python in a Nutshell wasn't much help.

[EDIT]

What I'm trying to avoid is

```
try:
    foo1
except: 
    bar0
try: 
    foo2
except: 
    bar0
try: 
    foo3
except: 
    bar1
try:
    foo4
except:
    bar2
```

where bar2 includes everything in bar2 which includes everything in bar0. I will grant that much of what I do in bar# is likely handled by GC, but I prefer to be pedantic, particularly when porting code (which is what I'm doing) before I refactor it.

Comment: What Python tutorial are you using?  All of them should cover the **try:** and **except** statements.  Also, the **with** statement does some of this.  What tutorial are you using?  Does it cover these statements?

Comment: Eek - that's horrible, please stop. (I'm talking about your C coding 'style')

Comment: @KevinDTimm: It's actually quite common, and used all over the place in the linux kernel. You might even argue that it is the only sane and fast way to do cleanup in C.

Comment: If you're going to exit the process anyway, isn't it unnecessary to perform any cleanup? [Related:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx) "The building is being demolished. Don't bother sweeping the floor and emptying the trash cans and erasing the whiteboards."

Comment: "close file descriptors" may not apply; it's usually handled automatically.  "free allocated memory" does not apply.  Can you provide any **specific** things that are Python-related?

Comment: Actually one of the things I'm looking at (this is a undergraduate interterm project) is whether explicitly using del offers any improvement over letting GC do it (I'm guessing no, that GC time is a function of total objects, not unreferenced objects), so I have code that has a sequence of del statements when exiting from a method prematurely.

Answer (score 4):

Python uses the exception system for this:

```
raise Exception("ERROR")
```

This will continue "unraveling" and cleaning up the stack until the exception gets *caught* by an exception handler. If the exception doesn't get caught the program halts, prints the exception and exits.

Read more about exceptions in [the official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Also, you described the use of resources. This is done the most through two patterns:

- initialization and cleanup, the resource gets allocated on initialization, and freed on deallocation (methods `__init__` and `__del__`)
- `with` statement, (methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`)

Both patterns will clean up correctly in the event of an exception.

Comment: I'm not so much worried about the stack as I am about what happens within the function (method). Within the function I can use the try: and except: syntax but this still leaves me with the same problem, as I understand it, which is then I have to unravel what I've done within the function. What I'm trying to avoid is code that looks like

'if condition: blah
if condition: blah
if condition: blah
'
or 

'try: foo
 except: bar

 try: foo2
 except: bar

 try: foo3
 except: bar
'

Comment: +1. @MichaelConlen. Also read about RAII which is the idea behind. As long as all states are held by object the blah conditions you mentioned will not take place. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: @MichaelConlen: "I have to unravel what I've done within the function"?  What does this mean?  Please **update** the question with specifics on what you might think needs to be unravelled.  Python already has garbage collection and context managers.  What do you think you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your need completely, but it sounds like you can use `try ... except ... finally`

Read more about exceptions and exception handling here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle errors, use exceptions. Example from official Python manual:

```
try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

Btw, you can raise your own custom exceptions, when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Along with exceptions, the `with` statement is often used with file descriptors in particular.

http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

FYI, although it's "bad practice", file objects get closed as soon as they get GCed, which happens as soon as they go out of scope, as long if you don't have other references to them. So this won't actually leave a file open:

```
def _readfile():
    f = open("path")
    return f.read()
```

But you will definitely be judged for it, if that's your thing :)